# XSLT sorting issue

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have an xml like:

```
<PersonList>            
<Person>
    <Name>Smith</Name>
    <Role>5</Role>
</Person>
 <Person>
    <Name>Star</Name>
    <Role>3</Role>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Name>Wars</Name>
    <Role>1</Role>
</Person>    
</PersonList>
```

In xslt I want to sort in such a way that if there is a Role 1 this should be the first Person in the list.
The rest of the Persons should be sorted alphabetically by Name.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us your actual xslt

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/PersonList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person">
            <xsl:sort select="number(Role=1)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
...
<xsl:template match="/PersonList">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[Role=1]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Person[not(Role=1)]">
            <xsl:sort select="Name" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
...
```

---

### Additional Explanation:

The expression `Role=1` returns a Boolean result. However, XSLT 1.0's `xsl:sort` instruction can only sort by text or by number. Therefore the result **must be converted to either a string or a number**, before it can be used for sorting.

I prefer to convert the Boolean to a number, because then the intended order is easier to understand when reading the code.

For the same reason, I prefer to state the `data-type` and `order` explicitly, even when they are the default values of "text" and "ascending" respectively.

In any case, if one prefers to sort as text, the  required process is **the same in terms of complexity<sup>1</sup>**:

```
<xsl:sort select="not(Role=1)"/>
```

is just a short-hand version of:

```
<xsl:sort select="string(not(Role=1))" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
```

which is the same thing as:

```
<xsl:sort select="string(Role=1)" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
```

The only difference between these three is in code readability.

---

*(1) One could argue that sorting numerically will be more efficient than sorting alphabetically, but I don't know that for a fact, so I won't.*

---

**Note:**
These differences are minor and largely a matter of personal preference.

Comment: As a rule, it's far better to avoid the assumption that 'false' comes before 'true', as some systems represent true/false as -1/0, which would mean true comes first. Also, in some languages, the translation of true might come first. Norwegian for example translates true/false to ekte/falsk- Probably not relevant in this case, but it's a good practice to avoid the assumption. Explicitly applying templates as per your second suggestion is definitely a better option IMO.

Comment: @Flynn1179 The representation of a Boolean as a number or as string is dictated by the Xpath specification and does **not** depend on the system or the locale.

Comment: I know, I was speaking of best practice generally, not XSLT specifically. Anyone who's more accustomed to an environment where it does matter might mistakenly believe this wouldn't work and introduce faults when maintaining it if the assumption isn't explicitly stated, either by comment or by specifying things like the data-type even though you're specifying the default, because it might not be the default someone else would expect. Anyone who removes 'unnecessary' code/comments like that is creating a minefield for their less-experienced colleagues.

Comment: @Flynn1179 Well, I can't fully agree with the first part (because really, where will it end?), but I agree very much with the second part - as you could conclude from the discussion (or rather from what's left of it after the moderators had intervened).

Answer (score 2):

**A simpler and shorter solution -- no numeric sorting is really necessary**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
        <xsl:sort select="not(Role=1)"/>
        <xsl:sort select="Name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. When Boolean values are sorted, `false()` comes *before* `true()`.
2. Multi-key sorting

Comment: "*When Boolean values are sorted*" Boolean values are **never** sorted as such in XSLT 1.0. They must be converted to strings - either "true' or "false" - before can they be sorted as text. Your solution is shorter (in that it relies on defaults), but not simpler.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Yes, and even in XSLT 1.0 false comes before true. As for simplicity, eliminating a call to the *number()* function and specifying the *data-type* and *order* attributes of <xsl:sort> does exactly that -- simplifies and shortens the solution. Less (unnecessary)moving parts !

Comment: You either haven't read what I wrote, or decided to ignore it. An explicit call to the `number()` function has the same complexity as an implicit call to the `string()` function. And removing defaults stated explicitly does not simplify anything.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Complexity and its antonym simplicity, is not the same as "computational complexity", which it seems you mean here. As for cluttering the code, this directly affects simplicity and understandability. My reaction when I see cluttered code is "Ewwee ... ' and giving the reader a better alternative.