# How can I sort nodes by a numerical value where not all nodes have that value?

Tags: xslt

I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root>
  <element id="1"><name>Red</name><rank value="1" /></element>
  <element id="2"><name>Orange</name><rank value="4" /></element>
  <element id="3"><name>Yellow</name><rank value="3" /></element>
  <element id="4"><name>Green</name><rank value="2" /></element>
  <element id="5"><name>Blue</name><rank value="5" /></element>
  <element id="6"><name>Indigo</name></element>
  <element id="6"><name>Violet</name></element>
</root>
```

I'd like to sort by numeric rank and have the un-ranked elements float to the bottom, like this:

- Red
- Green
- Yellow
- Orange
- Blue
- Indigo
- Violet

The order of Indigo/Violet is not relevant to me.

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
      <xsl:sort select="rank/@value" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:text>* </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="name" /><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But my output looks like this:

- Indigo
- Violet
- Red
- Green
- Yellow
- Orange
- Blue

All of the ranked items are in fact in order, but they are at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a more general approach:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
        <xsl:sort select="number(boolean(rank/@value))" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:sort select="rank/@value" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

See explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290573/3016153

Comment: Oh, I really like that: sort by presence-of-value *and then* by rank value. I'm accepting this answer since I think it's more clever than mine, and would also work with non-numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after a bit of tinkering.

Since I'm using a numeric sort criteria, I can sort `descending` instead of `ascending`, and then flipping the sign of the numeric argument being sorted:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="element">
  <xsl:sort select="-(rank/@value)" data-type="number" order="descending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This gives the desired order:

- Red
- Green
- Yellow
- Orange
- Blue
- Indigo
- Violet

Answer (score 0):

```
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element">
      <xsl:sort select="not(rank/@value)"/>
      <xsl:sort select="rank/@value" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
```